# How to include highstock in the bower.json instead of highchart

Tags: bower, highcharts

I only want highstock in my project, but if I put

```
 "highcharts": "v4.0.4",
```

Then it will generate the link:

```
<script src="bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
```

but all I need is

```
<script src="/bower_components/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
```

If I have both, then I will run into the Highchart error of duplicate definition.
How do you guys solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you set `highcharts: "v4.0.4"`? It is a bit different than suggested installation from bower in the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-bower).

Comment: I can include the latest version of highcharts, but my issue is still valid.

Comment: I mean you said `Then it will generate the link:`. What exactly generates that link? I'm not an expert in bower, but you can manually add `<script src="/bower_components/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>` in your file which needs to render a chart.

Comment: ah i use gulp to auto import the sources, so i think that's the point i am going to start with

Comment: Good idea. Probably your gulp script should differentiate `highcharts: 'v4.0.4'` and something like `highstock: 'v4.2.2'` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is that 
I will first do  `"highcharts": "v4.0.4",`
Then define the main file to include is highstock.js.